# ¿Como obtener el valor de un JComboBox?

Tags: java

Necesito agregar a un vector los nombres que se escogen de varios JComboBox, pero no se de que manera hacerlo.

lo intente con estos dos metodos:
  //Para obtener el nombre que se selecciona
  public String getNombre1(){

```
guiID.getCBNombre1().addItemListener(new ItemListener(){ //addItemListener, para que los items puedan ser escuchados

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evento){

    if(evento.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
      nombre = guiID.jugadoresSecundarios(guiID.perdido,guiID.vectorNombres)[guiID.getCBNombre1().getSelectedIndex()];
    }
  }
});

return nombre;
```

}

public String[] getColocarCampos(int cantJ){

```
String campSelec[] = new String[cantJ];

while(cantJ>0){
  if(cantJ==4){
    campSelec[3]=getNombre4();
  }else if(cantJ==3){
    campSelec[2]=getNombre3();
  }else if(cantJ==2){
    campSelec[1]=getNombre2();
  }else if(cantJ==1){
    campSelec[0]=getNombre1();
  }
  cantJ--;
}

return campSelec;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal, entiendo que en tu caso querés utilizar el contenido del JComboBox, te voy a pasar un ejemplo de cómo tomar directamente el value del String del item seleccionado. **Copiá** y **pegá** en una clase que se llame **Panel**, luego dale **"Run as java Application"**, y cambiá el selector para ver cómo funciona.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox<String> combo; // Si le quitás el parametrizado va a tomar como Object
    private String[] names;

    public Panel() {

        /*
         * Declaramos afuera del método e inicializamos adentro para reutilizar la
         * variable si queremos en otro método
         */
        names = new String[] { "Marcelo", "Roberto", "Lucas", "Gisella", "Ismael", "Mauricio" };
        label = new JLabel("Acá se van a imprimir los resultados");
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        /*
         * Inicializamos el JComboBox parametrizado o no, osea JComboBox<String>, le
         * decimos que lo que va a recibir es un String, qué pasa si no se lo ponés?,
         * nada, lo toma como si fuera un Object y en teoría tarda más en devolver el
         * contenido porque primero averigua de qué tipo de dato está recibiendo
         */
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(names);

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setTitle("Change JComboBox value");
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /* Metemos la interfaz directamente dentro del botón, sin implementar nada */
        /*
         * LAMBDA:
         * Esta manera sólo va a solucionar tu consulta muy rápidamente con un copia y
         * pega, en el código de abajo hay una forma más simple, ésta es através de
         * lambda que es mas moderno y corto de escribir, te recomiendo que veas también
         * el código de alternativo
         * 
         * Parámetro : event tipo ItemEven aunque no esté declarado Cuerpo: Un
         * condicional y una acción hacia el JLabel.
         */

        combo.addItemListener(event -> {
            if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                label.setText(event.getItem().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

Esta es otra forma de realizarlo, es quizás más larga, por unas líneas y unos caractéres más, sin embargo **es la forma más clásica**, sin utilizar lambda, te recomiendo que apliques ésta última opción o la siguiente.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/*
 * Acá implementamos la interface, tiene sólo un método por eso pudimos usar
 * lambda anteriormente.
 */
public class Panel implements ItemListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox<String> combo; // Si le quitás el parametrizado va a tomar como Object
    private String[] names;

    public Panel() {

        /*
         * Declaramos afuera del método e inicializamos adentro para reutilizar la
         * variable si queremos en otro método
         */
        names = new String[] { "Marcelo", "Roberto", "Lucas", "Gisella", "Ismael", "Mauricio" };
        label = new JLabel("Acá se van a imprimir los resultados");
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        /*
         * Inicializamos el JComboBox parametrizado o no, osea JComboBox<String>, le
         * decimos que lo que va a recibir es un String, qué pasa si no se lo ponés?,
         * nada, lo toma como si fuera un Object y en teoría tarda más en devolver el
         * contenido porque primero averigua de qué tipo de dato está recibiendo
         */
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(names);

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setTitle("Change JComboBox value");
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /* Tenemos que agregar ésta línea indicandole al código que ése JComboBox espera una acción */
        combo.addItemListener(this);
    }

    /*
     * Esta es la forma clásica de hacerlo y te recomiendo que en principio la
     * aprendaas así, luego más adelante por lambda.
     * 
     * Parámetro : event tipo ItemEvent aunque no esté declarado
     * Cuerpo: Un condicional y una acción hacia el JLabel.
     */

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            label.setText(event.getItem().toString());
        }

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

Esta tercera forma, sería utilizando una clase anónima (en este caso una interfaz sería) donde adentro mismo del botón damos todas las directivas. Un intermedio entre la forma de hacerlo con Lambda y la otra más clásica, ésta forma de realizarlo es muy útil ya que son pocas líneas de código que actuamos dentro de cada JButton, JComboBox u otro elemento, así como también evitamos poner condicionales como si se toca tal botón pasa esto, como contrapartida y en desventaja es que sólo se aplica a un elemento en especial, y si tenemos varios elementos tenemos que hacer el mismo código a cada uno.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/*
 * Acá implementamos la interface, tiene sólo un método por eso pudimos usar
 * lambda anteriormente.
 */
public class Panel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JComboBox<String> combo; // Si le quitás el parametrizado va a tomar como Object
    private String[] names;

    public Panel() {

        /*
         * Declaramos afuera del método e inicializamos adentro para reutilizar la
         * variable si queremos en otro método
         */
        names = new String[] { "Marcelo", "Roberto", "Lucas", "Gisella", "Ismael", "Mauricio" };
        label = new JLabel("Acá se van a imprimir los resultados");
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();

        /*
         * Inicializamos el JComboBox parametrizado o no, osea JComboBox<String>, le
         * decimos que lo que va a recibir es un String, qué pasa si no se lo ponés?,
         * nada, lo toma como si fuera un Object y en teoría tarda más en devolver el
         * contenido porque primero averigua de qué tipo de dato está recibiendo
         */
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(names);

        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        frame.setLayout(borderLayout);
        frame.setTitle("Change JComboBox value");
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 250, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /*
         * De esta manera estamos decalrando y definiendo el evento dentro del mismo
         * JComboBox, no hay que declarar en una línea aparte qeu este elemento va a
         * recibir un evento. A su vez creamos una clase anónima (es una interfaz
         * anónima en este caso) y ahí mismo declaramos y definimos todo.
         */
        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    label.setText(event.getItem().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();

    }

}
```

Por último, si ninguna de las tres te convence, podés cambiar una línea interna de los método que te pasé y hacerlo más leíble digamos:

```
        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    /* Modificamos esta linea, ahora utilizamos getSelectedItem() y toString() */
                    label.setText(combo.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Esta forma es más agradable e intuitiva al momento de llamar a un String que está dentro de un JComboBox.

Comment: @roberto-rojas te dejé una respuesta, si te sirve y soluciona tu duda fijate de seleccionar la pregunta como solucionada, abrazos!.

Comment: me sirvio la ultima :D gracias